# What is the difference between test case, test plan, test suite and test scenario?

Tags: testing, testcase, manual-testing, test-plan

What is the difference between a test plan, test suite, test case and test scenario? Is there any format that Quality Assurance team follows or a generalise format to follow?

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion:
A test scenario is functionality that can be tested. Something that the user may want to do with your system and you want to verify. A scenario can have one or more test case.
A test case is a formal definition of a test. It defines prerequisites, an action, and the expected result.
A test suite is a set of test cases which are logically connected. Eg: test cases which test the same functionality of an app.
A test plan is plan how you want to execute your tests to reach your desired test coverage. It's a project document and deals with questions like: which suites should be run in all development iterations. Which should be run on releases. Who is responsible for functional testing, who is for non-functional tests. What kind of resources are needed. When will be the different tests executed...